# There's no oci8 on phpinfo() on Centos 8, PHP version 7.2.11

Tags: php, oracle, centos, oci8

I'm using Laravel with Oracle connection, so I set up OCI8 for Yajra.
After setting all of the requirements. (Instantclient, OCI8, Enviroment ...)

I have checked the `php -ini` command.

And the result like this: (it means OCI8 is installed successfully, right?)

```
oci8

OCI8 Support => enabled
OCI8 DTrace Support => disabled
OCI8 Version => 2.2.0
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version => 12.2.0.1.0
Oracle Compile-time Instant Client Version => 12.2

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
oci8.connection_class => no value => no value
oci8.default_prefetch => 100 => 100
oci8.events => Off => Off
oci8.max_persistent => -1 => -1
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics => Off => Off
oci8.persistent_timeout => -1 => -1
oci8.ping_interval => 60 => 60
oci8.privileged_connect => Off => Off
oci8.statement_cache_size => 20 => 20

Statistics =>
Active Persistent Connections => 0
Active Connections => 0
```

But when using phpinfo(), there's no OCI8 
[image]

I have tried to test the connection by this code

```
<?php
    $db = "(DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=My IP)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVICE_NAME=SID)
    )
  )" ;

    if($c = OCILogon("my user", "my pass", $db))
    {
        echo "Successfully connected to Oracle.\n";
        OCILogoff($c);
    }
    else
    {
        $err = OCIError();
        echo "Connection failed." . $err[text];
    }
?>
```

And it returned HTTP ERROR 500.

Maybe I have mistaken on something? Please help, it's take me more than 2 days to solve it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's possible that your webserver's environment doesn't have the Oracle libraries in the library path, but your command line does. How you set it varies.  Best to use `ldconfig` if you are using Instant Client, see the Instant Client installation instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have set the environment and restart apache, but it's not effect, then I restart the server and it's ok.

Comment: How did you set the environment ?